# MySQL JSON wildcards

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to obtain all IDs from table `A` of the elements which are in a JSON array in table `B`. My problem is that I don't know how to use wildcard symbols with JSON.

Table A looks like this

```
+-----------------------+--------------------+
| Identifier (TINYTEXT) | Filter (JSON)      |
+-----------------------+--------------------+
| Obj1                  | ['Test1', 'Test2'] |
| Obj2                  | ['Test3', 'Test4'] |
+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

and table B looks like this

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| UID (INT) | Object (TINYTEXT)  |
+-----------+--------------------+
| 1         | xyzTest1, abc      |
| 2         | xyzTest2, abc      |
| 3         | xyzTest3, abc      |
| 4         | xyzTest4, abc      |
+----------------+---------------+
```

I want to use `A.Identifier` as the input to get `B.UID` as the output, applying the filter `A.Filter` on `B.Object` using wildcard symbols.

**Example:**

I have `A.Identifier = 'Obj1'` and want to find all `B.UID` for the corresponding `B.Object` that contain `Test1` or `Test2` (`A.Filter`). In this case, the output would be 1 and 2.

The SQL code without the inner join I would manually use for this is

`SELECT UID FROM B WHERE Object LIKE '%Test1%' OR Object LIKE '%Test2%';`

Comment: I'm presuming that `Filter` is a text column of some type?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `Filter` is a text column of type JSON. I will edit my question.